# Find unused columns in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I'm trying to find columns that are not queried in Redshift tables, in order to drop them.
I tried doing this by analyzing `stl_query` table, but that doesn't provide very accurate results (because of views).
Is there some kind of utility that can help with that?

Alex

Comment: What do you mean by "unused"? Empty? Not used in a query?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I meant "Not used in a query?", updated the question